# Create border around radioButtons group in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way to create a border box around a group of radio buttons in Shiny?

Here's an example of what I'm attempting to accomplish:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with CSS like this:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML("
  
  #buttons {
  /*this adds the border around the buttons */
  border: 1px solid black;
  
  /* this moves the buttons away from the top of the page */
  margin-top:10px;
  
  /* this moves the text inward away from the left edge of the box */
  padding-left:10px;
  }
"))),
  
  
  radioButtons("buttons", 
                             label = "Elections",
                             choices = c("Presidential","Midterms","Both")))

server <- function(...){}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The developer tools in the browser are super useful for finding different html elements and playing around with modifying their appearance using css. Here's a link to more about how to include CSS in shiny apps: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html